# Insert data to sql databse using python django

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I am trying to insert the form data to sql database. Can someone please check my code and help to find the error.

```
def signup(request):
    print("Signup Started ") 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=PANKAJ\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=student_records') 
        print("Database Object :- ",cnxn)
        #username = request.POST.get('username')
        #email = request.POST.get('email')
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        data = request.POST
        
        for key,value in data.items():
            if key == 'username':
                name = value
            if key == 'email':
                email = value
        print('Username = ',name)
        print('Email = ',email)
        c ="insert into student values('{nm}','{em}')".format(nm=name,em=email)
        cursor.execute(c)
        cnxn.commit
        print("Data inserted sucessfully")
    return render (request,'signup.html')
```

Comment: which error exactly, may the use of prepared statements would solve your problems

Comment: function is running fine without any error but when i check my database data is not inserted there.

Comment: in vs code you can run it line by line i also would check if data has data and which form

Comment: You can try django orm quires instead of using cursor

Comment: Aside... you should probably have a read through pyodbc's [`Cursor` documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor) to see the correct way to pass in parameters instead of using SQL Injection as you currently do.